# What actually is "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" and how can i increase the Memory for Java?

Tags: java, linux, memory, heap-memory, wowza

Actually i am running `Wowza Media Server` on `CentOS v6.3 64-bit` Linux. Then it used to be suddenly stopped in some days and whenever i check the logs, i always see:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

If i have to increase the memory rooms for Java:

- how can i simply do it please?
- have 72GB in my Dedicated Server, and 60GB is always free, can i give all 60GB to Java like that please?

Comment: 64-bit CentOS v6.3. It is showing like that in logs. Doesn't seems anything funny.

Comment: i'm sorry, but it WOULD be VERY funny if you had 72GB ram and a x86 arch. however check if your installed JRE is x86. if it is so, java cannot use more than 2GB.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Comment: how much mem reserved java process when OOME? how much mem is free?

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean. My RAM is always 60GB (at least) free.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the amount of memory allocated for use by your JVM using the -Xms and -Xmx command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust memory usage by setting up -Xms and Xmx parameters in setenv.sh file of Wowza under the bin directory.

Comment: How MUCH should i (or) can i give up to, please? (since as i mentioned, i have 60GB free). And also, the file seems a bit difficult to understand. At which particular place do i need to modify, please?

Comment: The answer to "How much" is really depends on your system and usage. You can experiment it by monitoring system for a while. (There might be a guide about it in Wowza docs, I'm not too sure). There's a line in my setenv.sh file as `JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx1200M"` which sets maximum memory usage as 1200MB. You can look for a similiar line and edit it.

Comment: @シリウス HotSpot's default, without -Xmx, is just 1 GB, so increase this to 8 GB for a start.

Comment: Isn't the default maximum for a 64 bits server VM dependent on the total memory available nowadays? In any case given the problem description I would suspect a memory leak in this media server application.